# grep match till the first occurence of a character

Tags: grep

I am tying to grep `<span class="c7">` from the below

```
<span class="c7"></span>
```

I am trying:

```
$ echo '<span class="c7"></span>'| grep -o "<span.*[^>]>"
<span class="c7"></span>
```

I am getting the above. So how to get only `<span class="c7">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<span class="c7"></span>'| grep -o "<span[^>]*>"
```

Your `.*` is greedy, it matched the first `>` and beyond. My `[^>]*` is also greedy, but it cannot match anything that includes `>`, so `>` in the pattern matches the first occurrence of `>` in the input for sure.